# How SP generates ID for each list item

Tags: external-list, list-item

When you click open an item in an external list, you have a url like this:

```
DispForm.aspx?ID=__ck8100530003000300030013008300g40000300&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fswsudc07%3A9200%2FLists%2FQuote%2FQuote%2520List%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x0
```

I want to know how the `ID=__ck8100530003000300030013008300g40000300` is generated, so I can open an item from elsewhere.

I'm using SP 2013.

Comment: Can you please confirm which version of SharePoint you are using? In the versions of SharePoint I've seen, the ID number is a positive integer.

Comment: My answer below should work with SP2013 as well.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an item in a list, SharePoint assigns it a unique ID that it keeps for its entire life.  This ID is what you are seeing in the URL for `DispForm.aspx`.  If you need to be able to create URLs that link directly to a specific item, you will need to query the SharePoint list to get the ID, and then generate the URL yourself.

Two easy ways to query a SharePoint list's items programmatically are using the [REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798339.aspx) or Web Services, namely [Lists.GetListItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/websvclists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

If you do not need it to be 100% programmatic, you might simply create a view that shows the list item's ID, export your list items to Excel, and then build links using Excel's [HYPERLINK function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/hyperlink-function-HP010342583.aspx).

Comment: Hi again, I'm trying to open this list item from another external list (a WIP list), to open the original Quote item for this particular WIP (in a modal dialog). Do you know if I should use a calculated column or if there's other ways to do it? Thanks again!! :)

Comment: Yes, you can use a calculated column, but it will not be clickable.  Here's an idea on how to make it clickable. http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/how-to-open-hyperlinks-in-a-new-window-or-not/

Comment: Thanks!! I'll give it a try now! just wondering if it's possible to open in a modal dialog..?

Comment: Yes, if the link you generate points to DispForm.aspx like above.

Comment: In the REST API link, it says: PartsDataContext context = new PartsDataContext(
  new Uri("http://localhost/sites/sharepointlist/_vti_bin/listdata.svc")); The only link I can find is: http://swsudc07:9200/_vti_bin/listdata.svc it seems 2010 and 2013 has a different structure..?

Comment: They both have the same structure.  The listdata.svc is in multiple places.  Each site has its own copy so you can get data just from that site.  Your swsudc07 URL would retrieve data from lists on your main site.  If you had a subsite, the URL might be http://swsudc07:9200/mysite/mysubsite/_vti_bin/listdata.svc.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm now trying to use the ClientContext, not sure if you know about it, I'm getting an 403 error, are you be able to look at this question when you got a chance? thanks very much!! http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83864/clientcontext-executequery-giving-an-error-the-remote-server-returned-an-erro